How can I deploy prediction model in Google cloud to show the result in google sheet?
How can I deploy a prediction model in Google cloud to show the result in google Sheets?
is GC the best way?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can write to a spreadsheet through the Sheets API.

Provide [mcve].
